# Is there a way to conditionally set the default padding to one specific edge?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to use the default padding on the trailing edge but only if a condition is true.

It is important for me to use the default padding and not a value so SwiftUI can set it for me.

This is my current setup using a ternary operator:

```
MyView()
    .padding(condition ? .trailing : /* what here?*/)
```

using nil or .none do not work and will give me an error

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/padding(_:_:)) for `padding`’s `length` parameter says: “If you set the value to nil, SwiftUI uses a platform-specific default amount.”

So you can always specify a trailing padding but set the length to `nil` to get the default and to `0` for no padding:

```
MyView()
    .padding(.trailing, condition ? nil : 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

The argument of `padding` can be specified with an *Array-like*/*OptionSet-like* syntax

```
.padding([.trailing])
```

you can simply write

```
.padding(condition ? .trailing : [])
```

Answer (score 1):

In simple case you can set just zero or any other default value you need :)

```swift
.padding(condition ? .trailing : 0)
```

But if needs to apply modifier by condition, you can use a `View` extension with `if` method (more details [here](https://www.avanderlee.com/swiftui/conditional-view-modifier/)):

```swift
extension View {
    @ViewBuilder func `if`<Content: View>(_ condition: Bool, transform: (Self) -> Content) -> some View {
        if condition {
            transform(self)
        } else {
            self
        }
    }
}
```

And then in your code:

```swift
MyView()
    .if(condition) { 
        $0.padding(.trailing)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an if statement. If do you not want to use that you can use a view modifier.

Here is the code for the view modifier:

```
struct MyPadding: ViewModifier {
    var condition: Bool
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if condition{
            content
                .padding(.trailing)
        } else {
            content
        }
    }
    init(condition: Bool) {
        self.condition = condition
    }
}
```

You can add an extension to view to use this more easy:

```
extension View{
    func IfPadding(condition: Bool){ -> some View
        modifier(MyPadding(condition: condition))
    }
}
```

And here is how to use it:

```
struct ContentView: View{
    var body: some View{
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .IfPadding(condition: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to avoid using `if else` like this when possible - SwiftUI redraws the entire view, which could break animations